# Avoid aggregation error in groupby after merging dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe -

emp10

```
    empno   ename   job        mgr   hiredate    sal    comm    deptno
6   7782    CLARK   MANAGER   7839.0 1981-06-09  2450   NaN      10
8   7839    KING    PRESIDENT NaN    1981-11-17  5000   NaN      10
13  7934    MILLER  CLERK    7782.0  1982-01-23  1300   NaN      10
```

emp bonus

```
    empno   received    type
0   7934    2005-03-17  1
1   7934    2005-02-15  2
2   7839    2005-02-15  3
3   7782    2005-02-15  1
```

And if i sum the salary of all the employees from emp, you can see that it is 8750 at the moment.

```
emp10['sal'].sum()
8750
```

Now, I want to join both the dataframe to also calculate the bonus of all the employees.

```
emp10bonus = emp10.merge(emp_bonus, on='empno')
def get_bonus(row):
    if row['type'] == 1:
        bonus = row['sal']*0.1
    elif row['type'] == 2:
        bonus = row['sal']* 0.2
    else:
        bonus = row['sal']* 0.3
    return bonus

emp10bonus['bonus'] = emp10bonus.apply(get_bonus, axis=1)

   empno    ename   job         mgr      hiredate   sal   comm  deptno  received  type  bonus
0   7782    CLARK   MANAGER   7839.0    1981-06-09  2450.  NaN   10   2005-02-15    1   245.0
1   7839    KING    PRESIDENT   NaN     1981-11-17  5000.  NaN   10   2005-02-15    3   1500.0
2   7934    MILLER  CLERK     7782.0    1982-01-23  1300.  NaN   10   2005-03-17    1   130.0
3   7934    MILLER  CLERK     7782.0    1982-01-23  1300.  NaN   10   2005-02-15    2   260.0
```

Now, if i try to calculate the sum, i am getting wrong result.

```
emp10bonus.groupby('empno')[['sal','bonus']].sum()

         sal    bonus
empno       
7782    2450    245.0
7839    5000    1500.0
7934    2600    390.0

emp10bonus.groupby('empno')[['sal','bonus']].sum()['sal'].sum()
10050
```

The two bonuses of Miller in emp bonus table causing double counting of his salary when joining both the tables.

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Since the time is not something you care about, you can first aggregate the emp bonus table to contain only one record per employee and then do your merge.

Comment: It appears you have a duplicate bonus record for emp 7934.  You should eliminate duplicate bonus records then merge so you get a 1 to one join and not produce cartesian joins with one to many relationships.

Comment: @ScottBoston No the bonus is right. That employee got two bonuses and every other person gets only one. An employee can have double bonus, I want to avoid double counting of salary when doing groupby operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
emp10bonus = emp10.merge(emp_bonus, on='empno')
emp10bonus['multiplier'] = np.select([emp10bonus['type']==1, emp10bonus['type']==2],[.1,.2],.3)
emp10bonus = emp10bonus.eval('bonus = sal*multiplier')
emp10bonus.groupby('empno').agg({'sal':'first','bonus':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
        sal   bonus
empno              
7782   2450   245.0
7839   5000  1500.0
7934   1300   390.0
```